# Objectify - can subclasses of the same entity have the same id?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, objectify

say I have these classes

```
@Entity 
class Animal { @Id Long id; }

@Subclass
class Dog extends Animal {}

@Subclass 
class Cat extends Animal {}
```

Can I be certain that there is no overlap between the ids of Dog and the ids of Cat. In other words, given an id of a Dog, is it safe to do this:

```
ofy().load().type(Animal.class).id(idOfADog)
```

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: Yes.

All `@Subclass`es are stored with the same 'kind' as the declared `@Entity`. That is, all your Dogs and Cats are Animals as far as GAE is concerned. There's an extra discriminator property on subclasses which tells Objectify to instantiate the correct subclass, but this does not affect object identity (it's not part of the key).